# Problems accessing local and remote files on Android

Tags: android

I have some problems accessing local files on my `Android` Application. I use `FileInputStream`class to access to a file on the SD card without any problems.
The issue appears when I close my application and add a new file to the SD Card manually. When I try to access this new one on my application it is not accessible (not found).
I think it has to be related to the `cache` that Android manage for every application.

I would like to clean this `cache` when my application is closed. Maybe it is due to the fact that when I close the application. (the activity) it is stopped but not closed, and the `cache`is not cleaned.

Anyone has this trouble? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. On SD Card was due to a bad coding. Refreshing the SD files was done on OnCreate method in the Activity and was not executed altough the activity was closed. I've changed to OnStart and works fine.
And regarding the access to remote files on a servers I've used URLConnection.setUseCaches(false) and now is working fine too!
Thanks